# jQuery toggle show/hide elements after certain number of matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In implementing faceted search, if the number of options is 7 or less, I will show them all. If the number of options exceed 7, I will show the first 5 only and insert a link that will toggle the display of these options.

My question in this case is, how to run through the list of matching elements, in this case `li`'s that fall within `.facet ul`, and perform this function. Secondly, I need to `.appendTo()` an `li` at the end of `.facet ul` that displays text based on whether or not I am showing all or some.

If showing all, I want the text to read "... Fewer Choices". If I am showing few I would like the text to read "... *n* More Choices".

A push in the right direction for each of these functions, or a complete explanation is much appreciated.

Code below for reference.

```
    <div class="facet">
  <h4>Brands</h4>
  <ul>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Really long brand name facet to show what happens with multi-line facets <em>(63)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Joe Rocket <em>(57)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Icon <em>(42)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Fieldsheer <em>(37)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Tour Master <em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">AGV Sport<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Alpinestars<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Cortech<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Element<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Fieldsheer<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Firstgear<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">FMF Apparel<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Icon<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Joe Rocket<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">O'Neal Racing<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Power Trip<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">REV'IT!<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">River Road<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Rockstar<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Scorpion<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Shift Racing<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Speed and Strength<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Spidi<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Teknic<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Tour Master<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Troy Lee Designs<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Vega<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Yoshimura<em>(21)</em></a></li>
   <li><a class="all" href="#">Z1R<em>(21)</em></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

The 'all' class is irrelevant here and serves another purpose. Feel free to disregard it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$('.facet').each(function() {
    var ul = $('ul', this);
    if(ul.children('li').size() <= 7) return;

    var hiddenElements = ul.children('li:gt(4)', this).hide();

    var showCaption = '...' + hiddenElements.size() + ' More Choices';
    ul.append(
        $('<li class="toggler">' + showCaption + '</li>')
            .toggle(
                function() { 
                    hiddenElements.show();
                    $(this).text('...Fewer Choices');
                }, 
                function() { 
                    hiddenElements.hide();
                    $(this).text(showCaption);
                }
            )
    );
});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ekolo/edit)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't expecting such a complete response.

How would I make this local to effect each .facet individually? Currently, if there is more than one .facet on the page it would count the li's in all facets and the toggler does not function.

Comment: I figured that based on Jer's response, thank you.

Finally, I'm having trouble with the logic of displaying all options, unless the number of options exceeds 7, in which case I would only show 5. This prevents there from only being one option in the  More Choices link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){

    var count=0;
    $('div.facet ul li').each(
      function(){
        if(++count == 7){
          $(this).parent().append('<li><a href="">Click here for more...</a></li>');
        }
        else if(count > 7){
          $(this).css('display','none');
        }
      }
    );

  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

my two cents

```
$('.facet li').each(function(x) {
    var warn = ''
    if($('.facet li').length > 7){
        if (x >= 5){
            $(this).hide(); 
        }
        warn = '.. Fewer Choices';
    }else{
        $(this).show(); 
        warn = 'test to append if less than 7 than seven';
    }
    if ($('#warn').length == 0){
                    $('.facet ul').append('<li id="warn"></li>');
    }
    $('#warn').text(warn);
});
```