# toggle show hide first x elements from a list in mootools

Tags: list, mootools, toggle, hide, show

i want to show only the first 5 elements of a list and hide the remaining elements, when you click on a "more"-link, the remaning elements of the list must be shown...

it's a bit similar to [jQuery toggle show/hide elements after certain number of matching elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411588/jquery-toggle-show-hide-elements-after-certain-number-of-matching-elements) but then in mootools (instead of jquery)

Answer (score 0):

A good solution could be a combination of CSS + Mootools

css:

```
ul{
   height: 50px; /* must be the same height as the 5 elements */
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

js:

```
$('moreLink').addEvent('click', function()
{
   $('menu').tween('height', [50, 200]);
}
```

Comment: hey Tibor, this is not a good solution in my opinion... it should be based upon the amount of elements (not on the height of the container) - if one would change the number of required elements or change the font-size then you can start all over again with searching the height of the container...

Comment: You can use [getCoordinates](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element:getCoordinates) to determine the height of each element. I had to admit that this is only handy in some use cases.

You can still loop through all list items and set display:none to the items with indexes larger than 4, then the "show all" link toggles all element back to display:block;
something like: `$$('#list li').each(function(item,i){...})`