# Toggle list elements in Jquery while showing the first few elements all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which has categories with subcategories. I want to show/hide the list elements but the catch is I need the first 2 elements to show all the time. I have tried to look for the solution everywhere and the closest I came was [jQuery toggle show/hide elements after a certain number of matching elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411588/jquery-toggle-show-hide-elements-after-certain-number-of-matching-elements)
but this doesn't seem to be working for me as my filters are little more complicated. Can someone please help me with this. Clicking on 'Sub-Categories' shows/hides links.
Also i must add the default state must be collapsed.

[My basic fiddle without any style](https://jsfiddle.net/yash009/1f6x7ez4/13/)

HTML code:

```
<li class="children level1">
    <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage">
        <span>Office Signs</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display: block;">
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/wash-hands-hygiene">
                <span>Wash Hands and Hygiene</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/entrance-and-exit">
                <span>Entrance &amp; Exit Signage</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/way-finding">
                <span>Way-finding Signage</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="children level1">
    <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template">
        <span>Shop by Template</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display: block;">
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/smoking-no-vaping-signs">
                <span>Smoking &amp; Vaping</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/parking-signs">
                <span>Parking</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/store-hours">
                <span>Store Hours</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/restrooms-signs">
                <span>Restrooms</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('li.children.level1').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).find('ul').length) {
        jQuery(this).append('<a href="#" class="subCat">Sub-Categories</a>');
    }
});
jQuery('.subCat').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).prev('ul:first.level1').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
jQuery('.subCat').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().find('li:gt(1)').slideToggle();
});
```

1. Subcategories parent
2. Find li greater than 1 (li's index starts from 0 )
3. Hide by default, using `jQuery(this).find('li:gt(1)').hide()`

code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/omYKzv?editors=1010

```js
jQuery('li.children.level1').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).find('ul').length) {
        jQuery(this).append('<a href="#" class="subCat">Sub-Categories</a>');
    }
  jQuery(this).find('li:gt(1)').hide()
});
jQuery('.subCat').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().find('li:gt(1)').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="children level1">
    <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage">
        <span>Office Signs</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level 1" style="display: block;">
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/wash-hands-hygiene">
                <span>Wash Hands and Hygiene</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/entrance-and-exit">
                <span>Entrance &amp; Exit Signage</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/office-signage/way-finding">
                <span>Way-finding Signage</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="children level1">
    <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template">
        <span>Shop by Template</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level1" style="display: block;">
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/smoking-no-vaping-signs">
                <span>Smoking &amp; Vaping</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/parking-signs">
                <span>Parking</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/store-hours">
                <span>Store Hours</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2">
            <a href="https://dev.holmescustom.com/signage/shop-by-template/restrooms-signs">
                <span>Restrooms</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This does work but i want the default state to be collapsed one and not expanded is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Yash009, make ul level display: none instead of block and use below  jQuery(this).prev('ul').css('display','block')

Comment: I am sorry should have mentioned, I want the default view as collapsed with 2 elements showing. I am so sorry should have specified better.

Comment: @Yash009, you mean subcategories before list , as solution in - codepen.io/nagasai/pen/omYKzv shows first two by default but subcategories is not positioned before list?

Comment: what I am observing on your codepen is it hides all at first on page load and on the first click it shows two and then on the second click it shows the rest. What I need is it shows 2 on page load and then when I click sub-categories it shows all and then toggles so on and so forth.

Comment: @Yash009, are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xMgKoL

Comment: @Yash009, updated answer to show collapsed by default

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Please mark my post as answer, if it helped you to solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript that do the slideToggle as this;

```
jQuery('.subCat').click(function () {
  var ul = jQuery(this).prev('ul:first.level1');
  var li = ul.find('li:gt(1)');
  li.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: How do i make the default as 2 elements showing and not all the elements showing?